sheaf of residue fields / maximal ideal sheaf
given a scheme $X$ with structure sheaf $\mathcal O_X$ over a topological space $\lvert X \rvert$, there’s the so-called étalé space $\bigsqcup_{x ∈ \lvert X \rvert} \mathcal O_{X, x}$, which is endowed with a topology such that $\mathcal O_X$ can be seen as the sheaf of continuous sections of $\bigsqcup_{x ∈ \lvert X \rvert} X → \lvert X \rvert $, see wiki:sheaf#étalé-space.
(note that i don’t mean “étale”, there’s a difference in spelling and meaning between “étale” and “étalé”.)
now the projections $\mathcal O_{X,x} → κ(x)$ for $x ∈ \lvert X \rvert$ get bundled into a map $\bigsqcup_{x ∈ \lvert X \rvert} \mathcal O_{X,x} → \bigsqcup_{x ∈ \lvert X \rvert} κ(x)$, via which the latter space can be endowed with the corresponding final topology.
now if i’m not mistaken, the continuous sections of this space, that is of $\bigsqcup_{x ∈ \lvert X \rvert} κ(x) → \lvert X \rvert$ define an $\mathcal O_X$-algebra $\mathcal K_X$ on $\lvert X \rvert$ with local stalks given by $κ(x)$ for $x ∈ \lvert X \rvert$ with a corresponding map of sheaves $\mathcal O_X → \mathcal K_X$, whose kernel $\mathcal m_X$ is an ideal sheaf whose stalks are precisely the maximal ideals of the stalks of $\mathcal O_X$ and we get a short exact sequence of $\mathcal O_X$-sheaves
$$0 → \mathcal m_X → \mathcal O_X → \mathcal K_X → 0.$$
to me, this looks like a very natural, straightforward and potentially useful construction, yet i have not seen it before in the literature and i know of no name for either $\mathcal m_X$ or $\mathcal K_X$. a superficial search for “sheaf of residue fields” or “maximal ideal sheaf” has yielded no results either …

are there names for these sheaves $\mathcal m_X$ and $\mathcal K_X$?
are there any uses for these sheaves? do they come up in the literature somewhere?
or have i made a mistake and the construction fails at some point?


If $X$ is not reduced I don't think this bundle of residue fields is etale

@FShrike i didn’t say it was.

The maximal ideals do not form a sheaf. More precisely, there is no subsheaf of $O_X$ whose stalk at $x$ is the maximal ideal at $x$. (What would its sections be? Hint: work affine-locally.) In fact, literally the opposite happens: there is a subsheaf of $O_X$ whose stalk at $x$ is the complement of the maximal ideal at $x$. This subsheaf is easy to describe: it is the subsheaf of (multiplicative) units, $O_X^{\times}$.

@ZhenLin hmm, ok, so i guess that the sections of $\bigsqcup_{x ∈ \lvert X \rvert} κ(x) → \lvert X \rvert$ do not have precisely the residue fields as stalks?

I have no idea. If I had to guess, it is probably something like the structure sheaf modulo the nilradical.
